# "Grit" vs "gritted"

Tags: american-english, past-tense

Dictionary sources tell me that the past tense of *grit* is *gritted* rather than *grit*. Why does that sound weird to me? Am I delusional, or is this one of those words changing in current usage? *Pet* is a similar case - I rarely hear *petted* used as a past tense.

Comment: You're [not the only one](http://literalminded.wordpress.com/2007/03/24/he-grit-his-teeth/). It appears that these past tenses are in flux.

Comment: @PeterShor That's one of the sources I found while googling that made me think to ask at all; I'd earlier just accepted that I must be crazy and changed my manuscript, only now I'm considering changing it back if it's really in flux.

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't know if by "in flux" you mean it's transitioning from a regular to an irregular verb, but [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+grit+his+teeth%2Che+gritted+his+teeth&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) doesn't seem to support that. It looks more like there's a fairly constant number of instances of the irregular form, even while the number of regular usages has steadily increased. Effectively, the low but steady irregular version is being gradually outnumbered.

Comment: Is there perhaps a difference between the two meanings of ‘grit’? ‘He grit his teeth’, but ‘Because of the heavy snowfall overnight, they gritted the road early the following morning.’

Comment: This usage of grit in the past tense is definitely US only. To my ear it sounds as weird as "writing someone" as opposed to "writing *to* someone".

Comment: @sml I can fully believe it's a US thing. A lot of "sounds weird to me" issues tend to be localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does that sound weird to you?

Because there is a small group of irregular monosyllabic English verbs ending in *-t* (e.g, *hit, spit, shit, knit, fit, pet, let*) that share the peculiarity of having Zero as their past tense **and** past participle form, too. So it's

- Present: *He **lets** her in. She **hits** him in the face.*
- Past: *He **let** her in. She **hit** him in the face.*
- Perfect *He has **let** her in.  She has **hit** him in the face.*

Now, this is a small class, and the verbs in it are pretty common -- this is how they stay irregular, of course; verbs that aren't often encountered rapidly become regular. And with a verb like *grit*, there's a natural tendency to conjugate it like *hit, spit, knit, fit*; but *grit* is rare enough that maybe it ought to be regular. One can't know everything, after all; so pick whatever sounds good to you and stick with it.

I was surprised to hear *petted*, too; but I don't know how recent it is. Note that it's transitive, though. One thing to watch out for is differential regularity -- transitive usages, especially causative transitive usages,  of irregular verbs may well become regular independently of the irregular corresponding intransitive.

- *He **shined** his shoes ~ Those shoes **shone** brilliantly* -- but not the reverse.

Comment: I'm surprised to see *spit*, *shit*, *knit*, *pet*, and to a lesser extent *fit*, in your list. AFAIC their past tense forms are *spat*, *shat*, *knitted*, *petted*, and either *fit* or *fitted*, although I couldn't say what the criteria are for choosing between those two.

Comment: Typically it's the transitive ones that get regularized. They're derived from the original intransitive, and as a new verb, there's a tendency to use regular endings.