# Does 'gritted' work here?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, writing

> "He gritted his teeth."

I can't tell if gritted is correct because both gritted and grit don't sound right to me in this sentence.

The dictionary says that both grit and gritted are the past tense. (Nowhere does it say 'grot' btw)

In the grit vs gritted they're asking which one is correct when they both technically are and the answers for it aren't useful to me, plus I am asking how it fits in t h i s sentence because I know grit can fit into other sentences, but I wasn't sure if it would fit in mine.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you about the past tense of the verb?

Comment: Personally, I'd like to establish "grot" as the past tense of "grit".

Comment: We've had this one before: [“Grit” vs “gritted”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50870/grit-vs-gritted). I'm not gonna check any dictionaries, but I'm perfectly happy that ***grit*** could be used as a past tense in the cited context.

Comment: Grit and bear it.

Comment: To answer your edited question, let me quote from the answer whose question you insist yours does not duplicate: *One can't know everything, after all; so **pick whatever sounds good to you and stick with it.*** If neither sounds right to you then perhaps you should choose a different verb.

Comment: Although I can't think of any examples other than the archaic "gird" -> "girt", there are a number English verbs which end in "d" or "t" and whose past tense is (at least optionally) achieved by replacing the "d" with "t" (or simply preserving the "t") rather than by appending "-ed".  In some cases I suspect this is simply a shortening of the "-ded" or "-ted" sound to "-t", but in other cases I suspect it goes back to the parent languages of English.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Google's Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grit%20his%20teeth%2C%20gritted%20his%20teeth%2C%20grit%20her%20teeth%2C%20gritted%20her%20teeth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrit%20his%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgritted%20his%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrit%20her%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgritted%20her%20teeth%3B%2Cc0), ***gritted*** is definitely more common.

[image: Google Ngrams Chart]

Interestingly, it appears that women didn't grit their teeth in any significant numbers until the mid '70s.

Comment: The Ngram is useless here, as it is perfectly valid to use the phrase in the present tense, and to do so is quite common.

Comment: So "_grit_ his/her teeth" includes both the past tense and present and it's still not as popular as _gritted_.

Comment: If the chart could be trusted then "grit" would be about 1/7th as common as "gritted", in this sense, and that would be frequently enough to make the "grit" usage "common".  Relative frequencies don't have to be nearly equal for the two forms to be considered "popular".

Comment: Wouldn't the present tense be _grits_ (because with his/her, it would have to be _he/she grits his/her teeth_)?  Otherwise it would be _he/she **would/will** grit his/her teeth_, no?

Comment: Watching the congressional hearing caused him to grit his teeth.

Comment: Good point -- I hadn't thought of that.  Do you think I should delete this answer?